# screen mirroring to LG smart tv

Tags: raspbian, wifi, screen, share

I have a LG smart tv with Wifi built in and im tired of always have to connect the HDMI cable to my raspberry pi 3.

Is it possible to connect to the tv via wireless like the screen sharing option on android?

I have read somewhere i can use VLC, but if possible ill just be able to stream video for example or will i be able to stream my desktop?

Exactly what i want to do:

- stream my rpi dektop to the TV
- use no cables

Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "stream RPi desktop to the TV", I read "remote access into your Raspberry Pi from your TV", and I think of a VNC Client as a WebOS app you can run on your TV.

Interestingly, there are such apps out there, just Google "VNC Client WebOS".

Then enable your Pi's VNC Server as [explained by the Foundation here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/).

You'll need a wireless keyboard and mouse, but that should allow you to do what you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: If all you want is to display your display contents on the TV screen, this really isn't the best idea from a security perspective. It's safer to use something that doesn't open up your RPi for inward connections, and only requires it to initiate an outward connection.